# I have a site coded with Html, CSS (Bootstrap), Nodejs, Express.js and I want to host it on a website, how can I do it?

Tags: node.js, express

Do I have to upload the Node Modules folder too? Or is there something I haven't learned about yet, I'm a fresher and this is my first time deploying a site.

Comment: try ec2 for hosting.

Comment: The solution will depend on the hosting provider that you're trying to use. Could you please provide more information such as what hosting provider you're planning to use and what you've tried so far.

Comment: @DanHarper Hei, so I recently used openode.io to test if it was working, and I was. Also tried firsebase but could not keep up to that too. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

you can deploy your site on any depolyment platform such as heroku, vercel, or netlify. You don't need to upload node_modules as they will install by themselves.

Comment: I have Domain and hosting both, I want to know about hosting it from there.

Comment: It depends on your host, since node needs to be run on the server, and how that works varies between different providers. Without more information, it's going to be hard to say exactly what to do. Here is a bit of information, but with an example for Heroku: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/deployment

Answer (score 0):

If you have Cpanel access, then you can do it by Cpanel, otherwise, you can use any FTP server like FileZilla, and by using your credentials, access your site and upload all the files in the Public_html folder.

[Check out this video for better understanding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XJEsFds7588)

Comment: Yes, I have Cpanel. I have uploaded all the files to Public_html but my CSS, JS isn't loading up.